# Can an L3 switch work with an ASA to make VLAN more secure?

Tags: cisco

I am learning secure network design but have a question I can't find the answer to.

Let's say I have a theoretical network like the following. The PCS and servers are on separate VLANs and are inter VLAN routed with ACLs providing security. Could the L3 switch (HQSW_INT) work with the ASA to inspect the traffic and make the overall internal segment more secure?

**Example**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Layer 3 ]

- should hold your VLANs
- can port-mirror your complete traffic so you have live full traffic view there
- can use VLAN ACLs to mitigate/limit LAN-side problems

[ASA]

- should handle extended ACLs
- can be configured as syslog to provie logs to the destination you desire